# $BE_USER detail in tca.php file of custom extension in typo3 6.2

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

I want `$BE_USER` detail in `tca.php` file of custom extension in typo3 6.2?

I have tried different options like
`$BE_USER`, `$GLOBALS['BE_USER']`, but not get any success.

Answer (score -1):

Did u notice that there are Extbase classes for backend users?

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\BackendUser
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\BackendUserGroup
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\BackendUserRepository
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Repository\BackendUserGroupRepository
```

Comment: How should this help in the described case? ´$GLOBALS['BE_USER']´ should contain the user information in the backend, right? It doesn't matter if it an object of an extabse class or not.

Comment: Sorry, I thought he just need the be_user details in an extbase extension and I didn't read the question well. My fault.

Comment: Is there any update regarding how to get backend user?